# Is it the public key or the key pair that is included in the x509 certificate?

Tags: certificates, public-key-infrastructure, certificate-authority, x.509

I use these commands to create a self-signed certificate, subject's key and CSR, and subject's signed certificate:

```
Root CA:
openssl req -new -sha256 -x509 -days 7300 -out ca.crt -keyout ca.key.pem -nodes

Server CSR:
openssl req -new -sha256 -out server.csr -keyout server.key.pem  -nodes

Sign with CA:
openssl ca -cert ca.crt -days 3650 -md sha256 -in server.csr -out server.crt
```

The CA signs the CSR with its private key, does this mean that the root certificate (ca.crt) contains the private key?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **private key is never included in the certificate**, certificates are publicly available.

The CA key is specified either through a flag or through the config file. When none is specified, the default config file is used (depends on how openssl was built) which points to `$dir/private/cakey.pem` for the private key (at least mine does, mileage may vary).

To properly use openssl you should really have a config file specifying the desired values. See [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21297139/how-do-you-sign-a-certificate-signing-request-with-your-certification-authority) for a lot more details. Or if you don't want to deal with the madness and giant pile of cruft that is openssl, use a more modern tool such as [cfssl](https://blog.cloudflare.com/introducing-cfssl/).

Comment: I specified the `-key` flag but still using the config file and complaining about "No such file or directory" for the key path in the config file

Comment: I recommend walking exactly through some posted examples, then tweaking the configs/invocation one you get the hang of it. openssl is notoriously prickly.

Comment: It's `-keyfile` not `-key`